# Railtie initialization of gem dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand the initialization process for Rails 3 plugins.  I have a plugin packaged as a gem that I am including in my Gemfile for my project.

In turn, that gem specifies in its gemspec that it depends Sunspot::Rails.  The gem itself gets pulled in and I can access its classes, but it doesn't appear that the railtie initialization code gets run.

However, if I add a line in my project's Gemfile for sunspot_rails directly, then the initialization code is run.

Does anyone know of a way to have my gem/plugin run the initialize code in its dependencies without having to include all of them directly in my project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274306/gem-dependencies-with-rails-3-engine-fail-in-initializer/4992478

Comment: Thanks.  It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but I think I've found a solution based on a similar idea.  I have to manually require the railties from my required gems (which seems odd to me) but it seems to be working so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [the above article and responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274306/gem-dependencies-with-rails-3-engine-fail-in-initializer), I realized that I was requiring `sunspot/rails` instead of `sunspot_rails`. It's necessary to require `sunspot_rails` because that in turn requires the railtie (which is not automatically required as part of having the gem listed in the gemspec).

[Here is a link to a very good article](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) on the difference between gemspec and Gemfile that helped explain it all.